# Mapping to an already persisted object

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Problem

I have two clasess - `Profile` and `Image`

Now `Profile` has an instance variable of `Image`

```
class Profile{
..
..
Image image;
..
..


getters and setters

..
}
```

Now, scenario is that

1) Image is already saved in an image table - as it was save separately using `ImageRepo` class' defualt `save()` method.

```
class Image{

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
private String name;
private String url;

..
..

//getters and setters
}
```

2) Upon saving `Profile` - I have the image's url in the incoming `Profile` object JSON

3) Now Since Image's url is embedded as object in JSON - upon saving `Profile`

I get following error.

> org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an
>   unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before
>   flushing

It is happening as it is TRYING to save the incoming embedded `Image` object in `Profile` JSON and there is no CASCADE - but that is NOT the intention here.

I just want to ASSIGN already saved\persisted `Image` object to `Profile`.

What to do here ?

```
JSON:
        {
        ..
        ..
        "profile":{
                    "name":"fsdf",
                     "image":{
                              "name":"sdfsd",
                              "url":"http://....." 
                             }
                   }

    ..
    ..
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not lookup the `Image` from your database based on the incoming JSON.

A very naive and trivial example:

```
public class Controller {
  public void someProfileMethod(String profileJson) {
    final Profile profile = // create profile from JSON
    final Image image = imageService.getImageByName( profile.image.name );
    if ( image != null ) {
      profile.setImage( image );
    }
    else {
      profile.setImage( null );
    }
    profileService.saveProfile( profile );
  }
}
```